# "Global" search of table contents from a form

Tags: ms-access, vba

I'm designing a text box and button on a form that I would like to have run a "global" filter to only show rows where the text I entered in the text box appears anywhere in the table that "feeds" the form (hope that makes sense).  The below code will return results for the first two fields (RIC and P_RIC) but nothing after that.  Can someone please point me in the right direction?

```
Public Sub Global_Search_Click()
DoCmd.OpenForm "Wait", acNormal, , , , , acWindowNormal
Dim strWhere As String
Dim lngLen As Long
Const conJetDate = "\#mm\/dd\/yyyy\#"
DoCmd.Hourglass (-1)
Screen.MousePointer = 11
DoCmd.SetWarnings False

If Not IsNull(Me.txtFilterGlobal) Then
strWhere = strWhere & "([RIC] Like ""*" & Me.txtFilterGlobal & "*"") AND "
Screen.MousePointer = 0
lngLen = Len(strWhere) - 5
If lngLen > 1 Then strWhere = Left$(strWhere, lngLen)
If lngLen > 1 Then Me.Filter = strWhere
If lngLen > 1 Then Me.FilterOn = True
If lngLen <= 0 Then Me.FilterOn = False
DoCmd.Close acForm, "Wait"
If lngLen > 1 Then Exit Sub
Else

If Not IsNull(Me.txtFilterGlobal) Then
strWhere = strWhere & "([P_RIC] Like ""*" & Me.txtFilterGlobal & "*"") AND "
Screen.MousePointer = 0
lngLen = Len(strWhere) - 5
If lngLen > 1 Then strWhere = Left$(strWhere, lngLen)
If lngLen > 1 Then Me.Filter = strWhere
If lngLen > 1 Then Me.FilterOn = True
If lngLen <= 0 Then Me.FilterOn = False
DoCmd.Close acForm, "Wait"
If lngLen > 1 Then Exit Sub
Else

If Not IsNull(Me.txtFilterGlobal) Then
strWhere = strWhere & "([ALT_RIC] Like ""*" & Me.txtFilterGlobal & "*"") AND "
Screen.MousePointer = 0
lngLen = Len(strWhere) - 5
If lngLen > 1 Then strWhere = Left$(strWhere, lngLen)
If lngLen > 1 Then Me.Filter = strWhere
If lngLen > 1 Then Me.FilterOn = True
If lngLen <= 0 Then Me.FilterOn = False
DoCmd.Close acForm, "Wait"
If lngLen > 1 Then Exit Sub
Else

If Not IsNull(Me.txtFilterGlobal) Then
strWhere = strWhere & "([RIN] Like ""*" & Me.txtFilterGlobal & "*"") AND "
Screen.MousePointer = 0
lngLen = Len(strWhere) - 5
If lngLen > 1 Then strWhere = Left$(strWhere, lngLen)
If lngLen > 1 Then Me.Filter = strWhere
If lngLen > 1 Then Me.FilterOn = True
If lngLen <= 0 Then Me.FilterOn = False
DoCmd.Close acForm, "Wait"
If lngLen > 1 Then Exit Sub
Else

If Not IsNull(Me.txtFilterGlobal) Then
strWhere = strWhere & "([ALT_RIN] Like ""*" & Me.txtFilterGlobal & "*"") AND "
Screen.MousePointer = 0
lngLen = Len(strWhere) - 5
If lngLen > 1 Then strWhere = Left$(strWhere, lngLen)
If lngLen > 1 Then Me.Filter = strWhere
If lngLen > 1 Then Me.FilterOn = True
If lngLen <= 0 Then Me.FilterOn = False
DoCmd.Close acForm, "Wait"
If lngLen > 1 Then Exit Sub
Else

If Not IsNull(Me.txtFilterGlobal) Then
strWhere = strWhere & "([RIC_NOMENC] Like ""*" & Me.txtFilterGlobal & "*"") AND "
Screen.MousePointer = 0
lngLen = Len(strWhere) - 5
If lngLen > 1 Then strWhere = Left$(strWhere, lngLen)
If lngLen > 1 Then Me.Filter = strWhere
If lngLen > 1 Then Me.FilterOn = True
If lngLen <= 0 Then Me.FilterOn = False
DoCmd.Close acForm, "Wait"
If lngLen > 1 Then Exit Sub
Else

If Not IsNull(Me.txtFilterGlobal) Then
strWhere = strWhere & "([PRID] Like ""*" & Me.txtFilterGlobal & "*"") AND "
Screen.MousePointer = 0
lngLen = Len(strWhere) - 5
If lngLen > 1 Then strWhere = Left$(strWhere, lngLen)
If lngLen > 1 Then Me.Filter = strWhere
If lngLen > 1 Then Me.FilterOn = True
If lngLen <= 0 Then Me.FilterOn = False
DoCmd.Close acForm, "Wait"
If lngLen > 1 Then Exit Sub
Else

If Not IsNull(Me.txtFilterGlobal) Then
strWhere = strWhere & "([HSC] Like ""*" & Me.txtFilterGlobal & "*"") AND "
Screen.MousePointer = 0
lngLen = Len(strWhere) - 5
If lngLen > 1 Then strWhere = Left$(strWhere, lngLen)
If lngLen > 1 Then Me.Filter = strWhere
If lngLen > 1 Then Me.FilterOn = True
If lngLen <= 0 Then Me.FilterOn = False
DoCmd.Close acForm, "Wait"
If lngLen > 1 Then Exit Sub
Else

If Not IsNull(Me.txtFilterGlobal) Then
strWhere = strWhere & "([EFD] Like ""*" & Me.txtFilterGlobal & "*"") AND "
Screen.MousePointer = 0
lngLen = Len(strWhere) - 5
If lngLen > 1 Then strWhere = Left$(strWhere, lngLen)
If lngLen > 1 Then Me.Filter = strWhere
If lngLen > 1 Then Me.FilterOn = True
If lngLen <= 0 Then Me.FilterOn = False
DoCmd.Close acForm, "Wait"
If lngLen > 1 Then Exit Sub
Else

If Not IsNull(Me.txtFilterGlobal) Then
strWhere = strWhere & "([EIC] Like ""*" & Me.txtFilterGlobal & "*"") AND "
Screen.MousePointer = 0
lngLen = Len(strWhere) - 5
If lngLen > 1 Then strWhere = Left$(strWhere, lngLen)
If lngLen > 1 Then Me.Filter = strWhere
If lngLen > 1 Then Me.FilterOn = True
If lngLen <= 0 Then Me.FilterOn = False
DoCmd.Close acForm, "Wait"
If lngLen > 1 Then Exit Sub
Else

If Not IsNull(Me.txtFilterGlobal) Then
strWhere = strWhere & "([ESD] Like ""*" & Me.txtFilterGlobal & "*"") AND "
Screen.MousePointer = 0
lngLen = Len(strWhere) - 5
If lngLen > 1 Then strWhere = Left$(strWhere, lngLen)
If lngLen > 1 Then Me.Filter = strWhere
If lngLen > 1 Then Me.FilterOn = True
If lngLen <= 0 Then Me.FilterOn = False
DoCmd.Close acForm, "Wait"
If lngLen > 1 Then Exit Sub
Else

If Not IsNull(Me.txtFilterGlobal) Then
strWhere = strWhere & "([LOCATION] Like ""*" & Me.txtFilterGlobal & "*"") AND "
Screen.MousePointer = 0
lngLen = Len(strWhere) - 5
If lngLen > 1 Then strWhere = Left$(strWhere, lngLen)
If lngLen > 1 Then Me.Filter = strWhere
If lngLen > 1 Then Me.FilterOn = True
If lngLen <= 0 Then Me.FilterOn = False
DoCmd.Close acForm, "Wait"
If lngLen > 1 Then Exit Sub
Else

If Not IsNull(Me.txtFilterGlobal) Then
strWhere = strWhere & "([SERIAL_NUM] Like ""*" & Me.txtFilterGlobal & "*"") AND "
Screen.MousePointer = 0
lngLen = Len(strWhere) - 5
If lngLen > 1 Then strWhere = Left$(strWhere, lngLen)
If lngLen > 1 Then Me.Filter = strWhere
If lngLen > 1 Then Me.FilterOn = True
If lngLen <= 0 Then Me.FilterOn = False
DoCmd.Close acForm, "Wait"
If lngLen > 1 Then Exit Sub
Else

If Not IsNull(Me.txtFilterGlobal) Then
strWhere = strWhere & "([WCR_EQUIP] Like ""*" & Me.txtFilterGlobal & "*"") AND "
Screen.MousePointer = 0
If lngLen <= 0 Then Me.Filter = Null
If lngLen > 1 Then strWhere = Left$(strWhere, lngLen)
If lngLen > 1 Then Me.Filter = strWhere
If lngLen > 1 Then Me.FilterOn = True
If lngLen <= 0 Then Me.FilterOn = False
DoCmd.Close acForm, "Wait"
If lngLen > 1 Then Exit Sub
End If

DoCmd.SetWarnings True
If Me.Recordset.RecordCount = 0 Then MsgBox "No results for this search"
DoCmd.Close acForm, "Wait"
DoCmd.Hourglass (-0)
End If
End If
End If
End If
End If
End If
End If
End If
End If
End If
End If
End If
End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Copy & Paste of code is evil. The very first thing you should do is move your code for one column into a separate function, and call this function for every column. This will also force you to think about how to make it work for multiple columns.

Comment: I can't see how this would even return any results for the `[P_RIC]` field. Looks like you're testing a condition; if it's `TRUE` then do some stuff for the first field; else if it's `FALSE` then you go on to test exactly the same condition again (and again, and again...). Surely if it's `FALSE` the first time then it's going to still be `FALSE` for the other 13 times? By the way, if you used `ElseIf` instead of `Else` (new line) `If` then you could drop the last 13 `End If` statements.

Comment: Cross posted here https://www.access-programmers.co.uk/forums/showthread.php?t=294445 and here http://www.utteraccess.com/forum/index.php?showtopic=2044373&hl= :(